# transferring android app from side server to google store

Tags: android

I have android apk on side server and users download it from that place. I did this because this is betting app and it wasn't allowed on google store. from 01.03.2021 google store will allow betting apps so I want to put mine also to google store.

What I want to know is when I upload new version of my apk on google store, will the users that have my apk from side server get update or not (I guess not...).

If not what is the way to handle this and transfer all my old users to new google store app

Comment: You could release an update of your current app that will forward users to the play store listing when it is available.

Comment: Yes that was my idea too. But it looks a little bit clumsy. (I block all functionalities and show some message screen which tells users to download app from store).
I hoped there is some better option apart this one

Comment: wait wait. @takecare you want to say that it possibile to put new release on google store and all the users that have old app from side server will get update from google store? Or they will not get update from google store and I need to create my own local update-guideline to tell them to install it from store?

Comment: I'm saying it won't (AFAIK). Here's a similar question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100224/will-play-store-update-a-sideloaded-apk.